# How do extension methods work with inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

I knew the first half part of the magic. Assume I have:

```
public class Foo {}
public class static FooExt
{
    public static void M(this Foo f) {}
}
```

When I invoke `foo.M()` the compiler changes it to `FooExt.M(foo)`.

But how about the inheritance? For example:

```
public class Bar : Foo {}
public class static BarExt
{
    public static void M(this Bar b) {} 
}
```

When I invoke `bar.M()` will it call `FooExt.M()` or `BarExt.M()`? In fact I tested it and the answer is `BarExt`, but why? What happens when I call `wow.M()` if I have another `Wow : Foo` but no `WowExt.M()`?

Comment: Just a calculated guess, but I think the compiler looks at the static type to choose which one it has to take. Did you try something like this? `Foo myfoo = new Bar(); myfoo.M();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler will look for the extension method whose arguments *most closely match* those at the invocation site.  If you have a variable of type `Bar` then the `BarExt` extension would be used, since `Bar` is more specific a type than `Foo`, and therefore matches more closely than the alternative method that takes a `Foo` instance.  This really is not very different from how ambiguous method overloads are resolved.

It is worth noting that this code will call `FooExt.M()`:

```
Foo bar = new Bar();
bar.M();
```

This is because extension methods are not virtual.  Since the variable you are invoking the method on is type `Foo`, the `Bar` version of the extension method will not even be considered.  *Binding of extension methods happens entirely at compile time.*

In the second case you indicated (invoking the extension method on a variable of type `Wow`), the `FooExt.M()` method would be used, since there is nothing that matches better.

Comment: +1. Since extension methods are just static methods with first argument moved before function name they use exactly the same rules as regular methods.

Answer (score 5):

> I tested it and the answer is `BarExt`, but why?

Because the compiler will choose the extension method that "best fits" the call.  Since there is a method that takes a `Bar` directly, that one is chosen.

> What happens when I call wow.M() if I have another Wow : Foo but no WowExt.M()?

Again, it will choose the extension that "best fits" the usage.  Since there is no method that takes a `Wow`, but one that does take it's parent class `Foo` it will choose `FooExt.M()`

Remember that extension methods are really just syntactic sugar for static method calls, so the same rules apply to them as "normal" method resolution.

Answer (score 3):

When resolving extension methods, the most specific type match will be selected. In your first case, `BarExt.M()` is the most specific (targets `Bar` rather than `Foo`).

In the second case, there is no `Wow` extension so the most specific match would be `FooExt.M()`.